# GASの同時実行の考え方がわからない

Tags: google-apps-script

Googleフォームにてアンケートを行っています
フォーム送信後にスクリプトが実行されます（長くて４秒程度で終わる）
１つのアンケートの回答者数とアンケート数が増えると同時実行は増えると
思いますが、GASでの制限に同時実行30/ユーザー
というのがあり、この同時実行30の定義がイマイチわかりません
１つのプロジェクト内での同時なのか、１つのユーザー（アカウント）が作成した
ﾌﾟﾛｼﾞｪｸﾄ全部での同時なのか・・
明確に回答されたものが見つけられません
この制限は、どのようなシーンでのものがあてはなるのでしょうか？
自分場合、１つのスクリプトで多数のスクリプトを呼び出して何かすることは
ありません　せいぜい１つか２つのみです
アンケートの回答が同時にドバっとあるくらいです

以上よろしくお願いします

Comment: `この同時実行30の定義がイマイチわかりません`について、`１つのアンケートの回答者数とアンケート数が増えると同時実行は増える`から、今の場合、Google Formから同時にSubmitして回答が正しくGoogle Formへ保存される人数の最大数が30との内容です。ただし、同時Submitが30として、それらの回答はGoogle Formへ保存されますが、`フォーム送信後にスクリプトが実行されます`から、もしもスクリプトの中で値をスプレッドシートなどに配置している場合は、同時Submitがあると正しく値を配置できない可能性があることにご注意ください。このような場合はLockServiceを使用すると回避できます。英語で恐縮ですが、こちらの情報がお役に立つかもしれません。https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/09/15/benchmark-concurrent-writing-to-google-spreadsheet-using-form/

Comment: Formの送信にその制限がある事は知りませんでした。
となると　送信後のスクリプト云々ではなくなり
根本的な事を考えないといけないのですね
参考urlを拝読しましたが　理解するのに少し時間がかかります
ありがとうございました

Comment: 今後の勉強のために　スクリプト同時実行の制限についての
実際の運用スタイルを補足します
例として次のようなシーンで使っていると思ってください
営業所で車両を100台保有し、
営業マンが朝、運航前点検を行い、その結果をGoogleFormで
送信します。この時、皆がだいたい同じ時間帯にそれを行うので
送信が重なる可能性があるイメージです
送信後にそのトリガーにてスプレッドシート内で処理を行っています
１スクリプトだいたい４秒程度でした
これが１０営業所あり、営業所ごとにフォームＵＲＬが存在します
つまりプロジェクトは１０あるという事です
こういう環境下で使っていると思ってください
会社ドメインでWorkSpaceに５アカウントの契約をしています
現在そのうちの１つのアカウントで全部を作っているため、
同時実行の制限を特に気にしはじめたところです
５つのうちの別のアカウントに分散すればこの同時実行数は
減らせるのかも含めて知りたいです
ファイルは共有フォルダに置いています